# jquery find() fails in new version

Tags: jquery, find

in earlier version jquery, the statement was accepted.

```
myTmpl.find('input[name="CFG-"+ groups2[groupLetter]]:eq(0)')
    .attr("id", name1);
```

in Jquery 1.9, it gves error:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name='CFG-'+ groups2[groupLetter]]:eq(0)
```

Me thinks that it may be problem with double quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe

```
myTmpl.find('input[name="CFG-"+ groups2[groupLetter]]:eq(0)')
```

supposed to be

```
myTmpl.find('input[name="CFG-' + groups2[groupLetter] + '"]:eq(0)')
```

Comment: spot on! that's the problem!

Comment: @george .. This has nothing to do with jQuery.. This was the issue with the way you were concatenating the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are messed up:

```
myTmpl.find('input[name="CFG-' + groups2[groupLetter] + '"]:eq(0)')
```